# Trying to update versions - DB Upgrade error at 5.48.x

Tags: upgrade

I have been trying to update versions, and have been hitting errors

I have stepped back and step through versions and the issue appears at 5.48.x  update

UPDATE civicrm_queue SET runner = "task" WHERE is_autorun = 1 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'is_autorun' in 'where clause']

I have searched but not found a similar issue.  How can I get past this?

```
Error: Convert "is_autorun" to "runner"]
```

Error Field Error Value
Type    DB_Error
Code    -19
Message DB Error: no such field
Mode    16
UserInfo    UPDATE civicrm_queue SET runner = "task" WHERE is_autorun = 1 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'is_autorun' in 'where clause']
DebugInfo   UPDATE civicrm_queue SET runner = "task" WHERE is_autorun = 1 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'is_autorun' in 'where clause']
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: no such field in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 922

- DB_Error: DB Error: no such field in unknown on line unknown
  Exception trace

## Function    Location

0   CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:922
1   PEAR_Error->__construct('DB Error: no suc…', -19, 16, Array, 'UPDATE civicrm_q…')   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php:997
2   DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, Array, 'UPDATE civicrm_q…')  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:575
3   PEAR::_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), null, -19, 16, Array, 'UPDATE civicrm_q…', 'DB_Error', true)   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:223
4   PEAR->__call('raiseError', Array)   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php:1928
5   DB_common->raiseError(-19, null, null, 'UPDATE civicrm_q…', '1054 ** Unknown …')    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php:936
6   DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php:406
7   DB_mysqli->simpleQuery('UPDATE civicrm_q…') /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php:1234
8   DB_common->query('UPDATE civicrm_q…')   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:2696
9   DB_DataObject->_query('UPDATE civicrm_q…')  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:1829
10  DB_DataObject->query('UPDATE civicrm_q…')   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:468
11  CRM_Core_DAO->query('UPDATE civicrm_q…', true)  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1633
12  CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('UPDATE civicrm_q…') /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FiveFortyEight.php:107
13  CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_php_FiveFortyEight::convertAutorun(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php:73
14  CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php:215
15  CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(true) /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:36
16  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php:89
17  CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:38
18  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:285
19  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69
20  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
21  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199
22  CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke('')   /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:307
23  WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)   /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:331
24  WP_Hook->do_action(Array)   /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php:476
25  do_action('toplevel_page_Ci…')  /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php:259

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you try to re-run through the 5.48 part of the import and didn't do a **complete drop** of the database before restoring from backup.

This might be the same as [Error updating to civicrm 5.50.3 / Drupal 7.9](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42130/error-updating-to-civicrm-5-50-3-drupal-7-9)

See also https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3504

Comment: I think this is dues to a failed update. I will try stepping back.

Comment: OK so the update breaks because of this Extended Reports.  https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41445/upgrade-to-5-47-x-fails-with-error-exception-api-error-db-error-constraint

Now past that - but upgrade to 5.51.2  runs but then looses all my custom reports from templates, and the custom reports dont work either.

CiviCRM is really hard to upgrade and keep up to date, to the point where it is getting silly.  This is my second day on just trying to get updated and the old version isn't that old.  The LTS version tells you to apply patches that simply are not available - dooh